# How to add user groups to ID token in Okta?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, okta

When using the [authorization code flow](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/customize-tokens-groups-claim/main/), is there any way to receive user's groups in their ID token?

I've tried adding a "Groups claim filter" with "Matches regex" as `.*`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to **Security** > **API** > **Authorization Servers**, and click on the `default` server. Click the **Claims** tab and **Add Claim**. Name it `groups`, and include it in the ID Token. Set the value type to `Groups` and set the filter to be a Regex of `.*`. Click Create.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work at first but adding `default` to paths (`/oauth2/default/v1/token` instead of `/oauth2/v1/token`) fixed it.

Comment: That's expected. Okta has a couple of different authorization server types. https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/auth-servers/ You can't add custom claims to the org authorization server.